# How to increase VRAM on a Macbook Unibody from 2008

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, graphics, gpu

I know the Geforce 9400M in the Unibody Macbook uses shared VRAM with the memory, but since upgrading from 2GB to 8GB I haven't seen an increase in allocation. Why is this, and is there any way to manually increase allocated VRAM?

Comment: I think discrete GPUs have their own RAM -- only the Intel integrated GPUs allocate system RAM.

Comment: The 9400M is the mobile/laptop version, it uses system RAM (https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-9400m.c2055).

Answer (score 1):

The Geforce 9400M can use a maximum of 256 MB of VRAM, according to https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html. So increasing the RAM doesn't increase the video RAM, it just makes more memory available for applications.